# QT QTextBrowser disable write position when left-click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextbrowser

I'm writing a QT application that includes `QTextBrowser`.

When the app doing some functions the function prints lines in the `QTextBrowser` and during write the lines if i press the mouse left button on any printed line on the `QTextBrowser` the app restart printing the lines from that line i pressed on.

how to prevent that ?

Example:

- all function output:

> Device user: xvalid 1
>
> Device model: alpha 16
>
> Device name: Samsoni
>
> Working stage: level 16

- during the lines printing if i press on second line with left mouse button this will happen:

> Device user: xvalid 1
>
> Device model: alpha 16 Device name: Samsoni
>
> Working stage: level 16

as you see the app will re-set the start writing point from where i pressed

Comment: try with:  `setReadOnly(true);`

Comment: this option is only to prevent user from delete the lines not solving the issue

Comment: okay, I have not tried it, I'm just creating my test project, but it would be interesting to provide a [mcve], is a user ever able to edit the text?

Comment: I am adding the text with `append()` and I can not reproduce your problem. How are you adding the text?

Comment: No i'm using `inserthtml` to prevent adding `\n`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok just a moment

Comment: Edited the original post @eyllanesc

Comment: Is that a [mcve]? Have you read the link?

Comment: Yes i read it and i need a lot of time to re-create a minimal example of the problem but i think the written example is enough and able to understand the problem

Comment: Well, in this case the main thing is that the problem is caused by insertHtml(). On the other hand an MCVE does not take much time, look at my solution, it is practically an MCVE. I understand the problem without needing your editing but the problem is that I could not reproduce it if you do not point out that you are using insertHtml(), so it is important that you provide an MCVE.

Comment: @John, it might be enough to understand the problem, but it is somehow not nice to force everyone willing to help to create a test example in order to try to reproduce your problem, just because you don't want to spend the time to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs indicates that when you use [`insertHtml()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertHtml) it is similar to:

```
edit->textCursor().insertHtml(fragment);
```

That is, the HTML is added where the cursor is and when you press with the mouse the cursor moves to the position where you click.

The solution is to move the cursor to the end:

```
QTextCursor cursor = your_QTextBrowser->textCursor(); // get current cursor
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End); // move it to the end of the document
cursor.insertHtml(text); // insert HTML
```

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextBrowser w;
    int counter = 0;

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&w, &counter](){
        QString text = QString::number(counter);
        // at html
        QTextCursor cursor = w.textCursor();
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
        cursor.insertHtml(text);
        counter++;
    });
    timer.start(1000);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @John then that means we need an MCVE, I tried to reproduce your problem but I could not, and the reason is obvious: I do not know how you have implemented your code, a query is using `cursor.insertHtml(text);`, not `your_QTextBrowser->insertHtml(text)`. Anyway if you want help you'll have to work hard and provide a decent [mcve] :)

Comment: Big thanks, the problem was solved by adding these codes
`QTextCursor cursor = your_QTextBrowser->textCursor();`

`cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);`

`cursor.insertHtml(text);`
instead of `textbrowser->inserthtml`

Comment: @John that's my solution, I'm curious, when you said: *unfortunately not solved the issue* what code have you tried?

Comment: I added only these `QTextCursor cursor = your_QTextBrowser->textCursor(); // get current cursor
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End); // move it to the end of the document` and added `textsbrowser->inserthtml` instead of `cursor.inserthtml`, that was my mistake, thanks again

Comment: @John That was my suspicion, analyze the answers before using it for it in my answer not only put code but I take the time to sustain it.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistakes, i just need very fast testing at this moment so i forget a lot of important rules and actions, thanks again for your help.